# How to filter system users from contacts in Odoo?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

There is a Attendees field in Calendar module and this attendees is connected to 
'res.partner'. The problem is, it shows all the contact values, how to filter values or show only users of the system in the many2manyn field?

```
_columns = {
'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Contact', readonly="True"),

def onchange_partner_id(self, cr, uid, ids, partner_id, context=None):
"""
Make entry on email and availability on change of partner_id field.
@param partner_id: changed value of partner id
"""
if not partner_id:
return {'value': {'email': ''}}
partner = self.pool['res.partner'].browse(cr, uid, partner_id, context=context)
return {'value': {'email': partner.email}}
```

and the xml file view is like this

```
<field name="partner_ids" widget="many2manyattendee"
context="{'force_email':True}"
on_change="onchange_partner_ids(partner_ids)"
class="oe_inline" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and the easiest fix is to either modify directly the `.../addons/base_calendar/crm_meeting_view.xml` file and on the line:

```
<field name="partner_ids" widget="many2many_tags"
    context="{'force_email':True}"
    on_change="onchange_partner_ids(partner_ids)"/>
```

to

```
<field name="partner_ids" widget="many2many_tags"
    context="{'force_email':True}"
    domain="[('user_ids','!=',False)]"
    on_change="onchange_partner_ids(partner_ids)"/>
```

if you don't want to modify the original files, then you can inherit from `view_crm_meeting_form` and make that adjustment.

Comment: @ShravyaShetty: When you update an `xml` file (or the `_columns` of a `py` file) you must restart the server and update the effected modules.  So in your case, something like `openerp --update base_calendar`.

Comment: Yes I know that and I have done all the things until upgrading the module.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see system users only then user **res.users** instead of **res.partner**. Like:-

```
'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Contact', readonly="True"),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it has lot of dependencies Baiju, changing like that does not work

Answer (score -1):

I would add a functional field to the res.partner class that determines if the partner is a user.

1. define the field in your model:

```
'is_user': fields.function(
        _is_user,
        type='boolean',
        string='Is User',
        store=True)
```

2. create the related function:

> ```
> def _is_user(self, cr, uid, id, field_name,
> args,context=None):
>     res={}
>     partner = self.read(cr,uid,id,fields=['user_id'],context=context)
>     if partner[0]['user_id']:
>         res[id[0]]=True
>     else:
>         res[id[0]]=False
>     return res
> ```

3. change the definition of your related field in the parent object:

```
_columns = {
            'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner',
                'Contact',
                readonly="True", 
                domain="[('is_user','=', True)]")
```

Note: you may need to manually populate the values for the 'is_user' field in the database for existing records in the res_partner table (run something like this):

```
update res_partner set is_user='t' where user_id is not null;
```

Comment: `user_id` is the Salesperson; `user_ids` are the linked user(s) for a partner.

Comment: I guess the following sentence threw me off _users of the system_  Does it work now ?

Comment: The problem is because OpenERP is using `user_id` in a very confusing way -- it should have been `salesperson_id` as that is what it is.  So they had to think of a new name, and chose `user_ids` (not the `s`) and made it a `one2many` field.  So to find out of a partner is also a user, you have to look at the `partner.user_ids` field (note the `s`) and see if it has something in it.